# Argument 'mmmController' is not a function, got string

Tags: angularjs

The error listed in the title is driving me crazy.  Why is angular so picky? What is wrong with my syntax?  I'm trying to define a controller & sub controller, with a route.

[plunker is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FCUF6u2pSGbdEeXiHjMu?p=preview)

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var mmm = angular.module('mdp',['ngRoute', 'mmm.controllers']);

mmm.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$compileProvider','$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$compileProvider,$httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                redirectTo: '/commission',
                controller: 'mmmController'
            })
            .when('/commission', {
                templateUrl: 'form.html',
                controller: 'commCtlr'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/commission'
            });
        $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
        $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);
    }])


angular.module('mmm.controllers',[]);

var mmmControllers = angular.module('mmm.controllers');

mmmControllers.controller('mmmController', ["$scope","$rootScope","$http","$location","$route","$log"],function ($scope,$rootScope, $http,$location,$route,$log) {


});

mdpControllers.controller('commCtlr',["$scope"], function($scope) {

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had wrong controller registration, `]` was in wrong place.

```
mmmControllers.controller('mmmController', ["$scope","$rootScope","$http","$location","$route","$log",
  function ($scope,$rootScope, $http,$location,$route,$log) {


}]);

mdpControllers.controller('commCtlr',["$scope", 
  function($scope) {

}]);
```